# How to get most freq items and its number in an array with PHP?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like below. I want to know and print most frequent items in this array and its number of repeating.

**Example array:**

> 

```
$tags = array("foo", "foo bar", "bar", "foo bar", "foo bar", "bar");
```

I have tried this code below, but it is not counting full 1 item, it is counting every word. To give an example for that:

*output:*

```
bar: 5
foo: 4
..
```

I want it like:

```
foo bar: 3
bar: 2
..
```

**My code:**

```
function getWordCount($someArray)
{
    $wordList = array();
    foreach($someArray as $item) {
        $item = mb_strtolower($item, 'UTF-8');
        $wordList = array_merge($wordList, str_word_count($someArray[$i],1));
    }

    $result = array_count_values($wordList);
    arsort($result);

    return $result;
}

$i =0;
foreach(getWordCount($tags) as $key => $value){
  echo $value . ':' .$key . '<br>';
  $i++;
  if( $i == 10) break;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use array_count_values, and sort to make it. **[Live demo](https://eval.in/814846)**.

```
<?php 
  $tags = array("foo", "foo bar", "bar", "foo bar", "foo bar", "bar");
  $count = array_count_values($tags);
  asort($count);
  print_r(array_reverse($count));
```